# How to use a localizable resx image in WPF?

Tags: wpf, embedded-resource, resx

I have a bunch of localizable images and icons in the standard `Properties.Resources.resx` file; they are mostly linked at compile time. I want to put them on some WPF controls.

In WinForms,

```
control.Image = Properties.Resources.ImageResourceName;
```

does the trick, is maintainable, localizable, *not susceptible to refactoring*, and can be done using only the Windows Forms designer, but I just can't figure out how to achieve similar results in WPF (xaml OR code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stored in your resx file is a Drawing.Bitmap.
You can convert it into a BitmapSource using the code below.
This code could be placed in a converter for example.
Personnaly, I have defined a MarkupExtension that take the name of the resx and the name of the ressource and call this code.

```
private BitmapSource bitmapToSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapSource destination;
    IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSizeOptions sizeOptions = BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions();
    destination = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, sizeOptions);
    destination.Freeze();
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: How is it possible that something as practical and simple as localizable images, is so unnecessarily complicated in the supposedly user-friendly WPF?

Comment: Well, localization and graphics have been rethought. It seemns they have been rethought independantly... and are no longer so easy to use together. However, even if it not a built-in solution, you have to write it once, and it becomes easy again to integrate a localized image